# Galaxy ace camera app does not open and shows warning:  ErrorMessageHandler.handleMessage(-1)

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-ace

After dropping device in water, I am trying to open my galaxy ace camera app, but it doesn't open. rather than it shows a warning message:

```
 Warning: 
   camera failed
   ErrorMessageHandler.handleMessage(-1)
```

How can I fix this problem and make camera launches properly, so I can take pics or record videos?

Comment: It looks like this question is asked from a developers
perspective. Please be aware that Android Enthusiasts is for end-user
questions only and it may be off-topic as per [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions).

Comment: I asked this question on stackoverflow but I got downvote and they advised me to ask it here

Comment: Well if you are writing a program then it belongs to stackoverflow. Or are you trying to open the Camera app? Then it belongs here. But you need to improve your question, add more details (e.g. especially code snippets).

Comment: Yes it is Camera app

Comment: Is the phone new? Have you flashed a ROM? Have you ever used the camera APP before?

Comment: 2 months I used to open Camera but I dropped in water

Comment: Take it back to the repair store to get it fixed. Water damage has obviously knocked out some chip-set used in the Camera.

Comment: Something has gone wrong with your camera hardware and app is unable to find what it is. Take your device to service center (as @t0mm13b said)..